# Python 3 - While loop not breaking out of the loop when the requirements are met

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, exit

My simple rock, paper, scissors code :

```
def game(item1,item2,score1,score2):
   while score1 <= 3 or score2 <= 3 :
          item1 = input("Rock,Paper or Scissors?(1) ")
          item2 = input("Rock,Paper or Scissors?(2) ")
          if item1 == item2:
                 print("It´s a tie! ")
          elif item1 == "Rock":
                 if item2 == "Scissors":
                        score1 +=1
                        print("Player1 wins and has a score of",score1)
                 else:
                        score2 +=1
                        print("Player2 wins and has a score of",score2)
          elif item1 == "Scissors":
                 if item2 == "Paper":
                        score1 +=1
                        print("Player1 wins and has a score of",score1)
                 else:
                        score2 +=1
                        print("Player2 wins and has a score of",score2)
          elif item1 == "Paper":
                 if item2 == "Rock":
                        score1 +=1
                        print("Player1 wins and has a score of",score1)
                 else:
                        score2 +=1
                        print("Player2 wins and has a score of",score2)
          else:
                 print("Invalid input, try again")
```

when I tried it out and reached 3 score it still kept asking me for input, it breaks the loop only when I reach score of 3 in both score1 and score2, why is that? Am I using "or" operator wrong?

Comment: Seems like you want to exit the loop when either `score1` or `score2` reaches `3`, so just replace the `or` with `and`. Also, make sure the initial values of `score1` and `score2` is `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `score1` or `score2` is less than equal to 3, will keep being true until both players have a score higher than 3.

The correct condition is to keep going for as long as both players have a score less than 3. The game ends when either of the scores become 3

```
def game():
   score1, score2 = 0, 0
   while score1 < 3 and score2 < 3:  # while neither have won
          item1 = input("Rock,Paper or Scissors?(1) ")
          item2 = input("Rock,Paper or Scissors?(2) ")
          if item1 == item2:
                 print("It´s a tie! ")
          elif item1 == "Rock":
                 if item2 == "Scissors":
                        score1 +=1
                        print("Player1 wins and has a score of",score1)
                 else:
                        score2 +=1
                        print("Player2 wins and has a score of",score2)
          elif item1 == "Scissors":
                 if item2 == "Paper":
                        score1 +=1
                        print("Player1 wins and has a score of",score1)
                 else:
                        score2 +=1
                        print("Player2 wins and has a score of",score2)
          elif item1 == "Paper":
                 if item2 == "Rock":
                        score1 +=1
                        print("Player1 wins and has a score of",score1)
                 else:
                        score2 +=1
                        print("Player2 wins and has a score of",score2)
          else:
                 print("Invalid input, try again")

game()
```

Output:

```
Rock,Paper or Scissors?(1) Rock
Rock,Paper or Scissors?(2) Paper
Player2 wins and has a score of 1
Rock,Paper or Scissors?(1) Rock
Rock,Paper or Scissors?(2) Paper
Player2 wins and has a score of 2
Rock,Paper or Scissors?(1) Rock
Rock,Paper or Scissors?(2) Paper
Player2 wins and has a score of 3

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

let me break  down for you ,

```
while score1 <= 3 or score2 <= 3
```

it says if score1 is less than 3 or score2 is less than 3. Here you have to consider two variables . Try this one instead.

```
while score1 < 3 and score2 < 3
```